# SQLite: query excluding rows depending on combinations of values from other columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

Apologies for the unclear title, but it's kind of hard to describe without an example.
I have a table which can be summarized as follows:

```
Position_X     Position_Y    Position_Z    ValuesA    ValuesB   ValuesC 
10             30            500           value      other     another
5              45            2             value2     other2    another2
45             0             75            value3     other3    another3
```

I need to extract data using specific criteria, but I have to exlcude specific combinations of `Position_X`, `Position_Y` and `Position_Z`. At hand I have the list of the combinations I want to exclude.

When I hit a row with a combination of these 3 values, the row should be excluded from the query.

So my hypothetical query would be (simplified for example)

```
SELECT ValuesA, ValuesB, ValuesC FROM mytable WHERE <other parameters>
AND ... <condition here>
```

To refer to the example, what query would be used to exclude the rows with (10, 30, 500) and (45, 0, 75)?

Notice that the list of values I need to exclude, on the real data, is about 40 3-value combinations.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Comment: SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-06-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a virtual table with a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH
excluded_positions(position_x, position_y, position_z) AS (
  VALUES (10, 30, 500),
         (45, 0, 75),
         ...),
excluded_rowids AS (
  SELECT mytable.rowid
  FROM mytable
  JOIN excluded_positions USING (position_x, position_y, position_z))
SELECT ValuesA, ValuesB, ValuesC
FROM mytable
WHERE ...
  AND rowid NOT IN excluded_rowids
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would make sense to put these combinations in a separate table. This would also make your query a lot shorter.

```
SELECT ValuesA, ValuesB, ValuesC
FROM mytable t
WHERE other_parameter="found" 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CombinationsTable
                WHERE t.x = x AND t.y = y AND t.z = z);
```

If you don't want to use a separate table for some reason, you would get something like this:

```
SELECT ValuesA, ValuesB, ValuesC
FROM mytable t
WHERE other_parameter="found" 
AND NOT (x = 10 AND y = 20 AND z = 30)
AND NOT (x = 20 AND y = 30 AND z = 40)
AND NOT (etc.)
```

Comment: That can be done but if possible I would like to avoid it, as the database come from an external source. EDIT: Just now saw your edit, will try that, thanks!